# Google Play In App Purchasing Issue - Error You Already Own This Item

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console

In app purchases on my app have worked fine for 2 years, and I think they are still working okay in Google Play with actual purchases. But recently when using promotion codes, or internal/beta testing, when I try restoring a purchase, I get the following error:

Error - you already own this item

If I try to purchase an item, it looks like the purchase flow works properly. But then once it is done, I get the same error above. And I can’t restore anymore.

I’ve tried all the advice out there on resetting Google Play/Services Cache, and this person several years back seemed to have a similar issue that was never solved [Error You Already Own This Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027802/error-you-already-own-this-item). Most other discussions on this topic are fairly old and outdated.

One strange temporary fix is that if I revert my Google Play store to factory settings (I'm on a slightly older 3 year old device), it will work again... until Google Play store updates, and then it stops working.

I was using this library successfully https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3, but I thought maybe since it is outdated this might be the issue. However, doing it even without this library (using official Google documentation on setting up IAB) still results in the same problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @AdamS did you found a solution?

Comment: @Shubh unfortunately I had to completely rebuild iap from scratch because the library just wasn't working. Following the Google docs and making sure everything was updated to latest versions ended up working.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you may create your own updated library.

Answer (score 0):

For issues with the Google Play Billing Library I would suggest filing a bug on the public issue tracker listed at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/contact.